# Group/Count in SphinxQL

Tags: sphinx

I am trying to get a count of records meeting certain criteria while grouped by two fields, similar to MySql

`Select City,State from Index where MATCH('"Blue"') group by City,State`

Works but naturally

`Select City,State,Count(*) from Index where MATCH('"Blue"') group by City,State`

does not. Is there a syntax that will allow me to simply return the Count as well?

Comment: works fine to me in Manticore Search v2.6.2 (don't have Sphinx at hand now, but should work there as well). What exactly doesn't work in your case? Do you get any warning?

Comment: was an issue once, where did not work without aliasing it, but was later fixed. Try `COUNT(*) AS count`or similar.